# Remove empty values from array of objects only if the value is empty in all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove the empty strings in my array.

This is my array:

```
let array = [
    { name: 'John', age: '18', address: '' }, 
    { name: 'George', age: '', address: '' }, 
    { name: 'Kevin', age: '25', address: '' }
]
```

I would like to remove the empty string values ONLY if it's empty in all objects.

desired outcome:

```
[
    { name:'John', age:'18' },
    { name:'George', age:'' },
    { name:'Kevin', age:'25' }
]
```

This is what I did but it removes EVERY empty string values:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(array[i]).filter(([_, v]) => v != ''));
 }
```

Comment: Can we assume that all objects in the array are the same (i.e. contain the same set of properties)?

Comment: @yuvin Yes , all objects are the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind mutating the original `array` object. Here's a solution utilizing some array functions.

```js
let array = [
  { name: 'John', age: '18', address: '' },
  { name: 'George', age: '', address: '' },
  { name: 'Kevin', age: '25', address: '' }
]

Object.keys(array[0])
  .filter(k => array.every(obj => !obj[k]))
  .forEach(k => array.forEach(obj => delete obj[k]));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this issue with a filter method

- get all the entries to be scanned in the array;
- for each entry, filter the array with it; if the output array is empty then you can delete this value in the original array

```js
let array = [{name:'John',age:'18',address:''},{name:'George',age:'',address:''},{name:'Kevin',age:'25',address:''}]

const entries = Object.keys(array[0])

entries.forEach(e => {
  if (array.filter(i => i[e]).length === 0) {
    array = array.map(i => {
      delete i[e];
      return i
    })
  }
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mutate the original array:

```js
let array = [{name:'John',age:'18',address:''},{name:'George',age:'',address:''},{name:'Kevin',age:'25',address:''}]


let result;

Object.keys(array[0])
.forEach(key => {
    if(array.every(e => e[key] === ''))
        result = array.map(({[key]:_,...rest}) => ({...rest}))
})

console.log(result)
```